# Storekit implementation on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watch, storekit

Apple recently announced the ability to make purchases on the Apple Watch.  I'm running Watch OS 6.2 and made a sandbox purchase on the iPhone, but there is no receipt on the watch (at least using `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL` code below)  Do we have to handle passing the receipt from the iPhone to the Watch ourselves?  My understanding was that there would be an equivalent receipt saved on the watch we could parse.

```
    private func loadReceipt() -> Data? {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return data
        } catch {
            print("Error loading receipt data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this?

Comment: @aj20010319 I was not able to yet

Comment: Maybe you could try implementing this: https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-ios/commit/00e61a87581fdffbb3f1f180365bf29e4d9bf1b1
It didn't work for me on watchOS 7 Beta 4 though.

Comment: @aj20010319 thanks for the heads up, I'll check this out!

Comment: @aj20010319 I can't really follow the Obj-C in the link, what should the URL be exactly? This is the typical production URL `"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"` are they saying add `sandbox` to the end of it? 

Comment: No, you still use the /verifyReceipt endpoint to verify the receipts. They are saying that the location the receipt is stored on the device is not correct i.e. the sandbox receipt is being stored in the production receipt URL. E.g.
The receipt should have been stored at: `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../StoreKit/sandboxReceipt`
But it is stored at:
`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../StoreKit/receipt`
Something like this should work: https://gist.github.com/aj20010319/279b93181bd0b6e250bb1fc0699c9a8f

Comment: Thanks for that @aj20010319 tested it with Xcode 11.6 Watch OS 6.2.8 but still not getting a receipt array returned

Comment: No idea what's going wrong then, maybe the Swift code I wrote is not correct or there is something else that needs to be done too. Anyways, for my use case, I used `SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()`.